# gparted: how to merge unallocated space with a partition

Tags: gparted

I want to merge unallocated space to an ext4 partition. But gparted seems to prevent this. I cannot extend the partition.

see screenshot: merge unallocated with sda5.

[image]

Comment: That ntfs partition, is probably just wasted space, left over from a previous Microsoft Windows install.

Comment: Thank you for the acceptance!  Favour returned, question upvoted!  **;-)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you have unallocated space *outside of the extended partition* (`sda3`) *which contains the partition you want to extend* (`sda5`) so I would:

1. Take a full system backup using [CloneZilla Live](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php)¹
2. Boot a [live environment of gparted](https://gparted.org/livecd.php)
3. Move `sda3` to the left (this will move both `sda5` and `sda6` as well)
4. Extend `sda3` with the now free space at the end
5. Move `sda6` to the end of `sda3`
6. Extend `sda5` still leaving 10% of the disk space unallocated between `sda5` and `sda6`²

<sub>**Note 1:** Yes, take a backup!  If you have a power failure in any of the following steps, your entire disk is toast!

**Note 2:** That leaves you some wriggling room to extend your swap or your data (or both) in an emergency.

**Note 3:** Yes, you can also extend `sda3` to the left and then extend `sda5` to the left but that will not give you the 10% spare (unallocated) space for emergency extension in the future and the entire process is going to take all night anyway.</sub>

Comment: Why reserve 10% OP did not ask for it. If they need swap in a hurry, they can add a file as swap.

Comment: In the good old days of separate command line tools, I could extend sda3,  move sda5, then extend sda5 without moving sda6. Can we not do that anymore?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes, we can.  (see **Note³**) I'm just stating an opinion *what I would do*... (edited to include `gparted` live)

Answer (score 1):

That image has a colored, not a greyed out checkmark for apply.

> That means you need to apply the pending actions and reboot.

- After the reboot, try to resize the partition.

> Dont try to shrink the unallocated space.

- Grow the partition you want bigger then apply.

> And of course reboot again.